# I'm level 50 and prefer solo play, what now?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, a few days ago my Sith Marauder reached level 50. I generally prefer solo play (yes, I know the second M in MMORPG is for multiplayer, but I'm one of those players who enjoys playing for the RPG/storyline aspect. I do occasionally group up with people, but that's the exception, not the rule).

I haven't completed my class story yet as I've just defeated Lord Draahg for the first time in Baras' Lair and I have to defeat him at least once more, but my real question is, what should I do next? I've started another character, but I don't want to abandon this one, but without joining a guild or grouping up with other players, what else is there?

Initially my plans are as follows:

- Collect as many credits as possible to equip my companions with the best gear money can buy
- At some point I'll go to Ilum, and look at the Rakghoul Plague on Tatooine
- After that I guess I'll wait to see what new content arrives

Comment: Doing lower-level Heroics by yourself is kind of fun.  I did way too many sidequests and levelled up way ahead of the curve, so I've actually been doing that since around level 25.

Comment: +Upvote - Great question. I'm approaching lv50 and wasn't sure what to do after either. I was going to complete all the maps and fill out my codex whilst saving up for gear and starship upgrades.

Comment: I also found this today which is a great guide to things to do when you reach 50. http://dulfy.net/2012/04/13/dailies-and-pve-gearing-in-1-2/

Comment: @DavidYell, great link, really useful - I find myself going back to The Black Hole because it's the easiest set of dailies to find. If you make your comment into an answer, it's definitely worth an upvote.

Comment: As you wish! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you reach 50 there are only so many avenues of play left, PVP and high end operations (8/16 man), you can join pick up groups to see the operations on normal mode to see the content, but if that's not really your cup of tea then you can skip it.

As far as solo play in The Old Republic is concerned you're mostly limited to your class storylines and planet bonus series quests.

I do believe that the Rakgoul Plague is a timed event, eventually it will end so it will no longer be there.

A small side thing you can do is to go and obtain all the datacrons in the game, some of them are not relevant stats to your character, but it does complete your codex.

Ilum is not a PVP only zone, there are quests there that you can do for daily commendations that will reward you with better gear, there are also daily quests to do on Belsavis and Corellia.

Working on your legacy level will help you when leveling other characters which was just introduced in this most [recent patch](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.2.0/legacy).

I do suggest the Imperial Agent storyline, it is absolutely awesome, although the others so far haven't been as good. As far as storylines go, I'm sure they will be adding more in the next expansion, once you complete your class quest, when loading the text reads "Interlude" which generally means that there is more to come.

Comment: Holocron farming is something you can do, it takes ages to do, thinking about the one on tatooine where you have to sit on a balloon for 30 minutes. I was nearly there but fell through the balloon :(

Comment: Hate that thing, happened to me too. For some reason I don't consider sitting on a balloon for 30 mins 'Playing' lol.

Comment: I believe they're called Datacrons. Also, if you have friend who can force push, you can save yourself a lot of time. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5yPGNYhl0E

Comment: Thanks - I've been doing the Rakghoul plague dailies to get my pet Rakghoul... I think I'll take your advice and go do some dailies or spend a bit of time on Ilum to get some better gear for my companion (I'm very selfish with choosing mission rewards) and revisit Lord Draahg. I'll definitely look at the Imperial Agent storyline in parallel with my level 14 Jedi Knight.

Answer (score 3):

what I did is alternate characters of different faction, so, I played one Republic char to 50, then one Empire to 50, then back to Republic and then to Empire. This so I don't do the same quests back to back.

Even so, after the 4th character it's still repetitive, so then I tried leveling the 5th-8th characters only on class quests/flashpoint/space combat (i.e. ignoring all side quests), so I do flashpoint/space combat until I'm at the level of the next class quest. When the next class quest is above my level, I go back to flashpoint/space combat.  Game feels more fresh to me that way.

8 classes, 8 storylines.  I'm not big in 'end game content', in fact, I haven't done one quest/operation in any of my level 50 characters yet (they all finished their storylines).

Answer (score 2):

Finish your class story and then continue your alt character. Update 1.2 has a LOT of incentives for having multiple characters. I hear all of the stories are great.

Answer (score 1):

The end game content for TOR is mainly set around daily quests which reward commendation tokens, similar to the plantary tokens, which can be exchanged for the high level gear.

There are multiple tiers of end game gear, which are all bought with exchanged tokens.

Since 1.2 there have been updates so that daily quests are available on Ilum, Belsavis and Corellia.

You can find a full guide on the lv50 armour sets, and daily quests along with rewards and gear costs on Dulfy's site, http://dulfy.net/2012/04/13/dailies-and-pve-gearing-in-1-2/

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately for you this game is unsuited for playing alone, all the best gear and best content is only available by multiplayer (fp/op/instance and PvP).